# Setting value of <GeneratePackageOnBuild> conditionally?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a common.targets file that I include in almost all my projects' "main" project files to handle doing MSBuild stuff that I want done in almost all projects. It includes (among other things) my desired defaults for various built-in properties. Most of the time, I handle that with `[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault`; for example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Authors>$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(Authors)', 'Robert William Vesterman'))</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, in the case of certain built-in properties, by the time that property group gets invoked, MSBuild (or something) has already given a default value to the property. For example, `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` will have already been given the value `false` if you hadn't explicitly specified it in the `<Project>`. So, the `[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault` idea doesn't work for it.

In cases like that, I use my own property, defaulting to `false`, to control whether the actual property's value should default to MSBuild's default or to my preferred default. For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild>$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild)', 'false'))</Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'false'">
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

That's been working fine for me (both for `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` specifically and for several other properties). However, I recently wanted to change it to default to `false` for my test projects. So:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'false'">
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' == 'false'">true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' != 'false'">false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But now `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` is always `false`, and I don't understand why. While troubleshooting, I eventually wound up with another property that I think I'm handling in the same way, and outputting the values of the various properties involved:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'false'">
    <Rwv37WhatInThe         Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' == 'false'">true</Rwv37WhatInThe>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' == 'false'">true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Rwv37WhatInThe         Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' != 'false'">false</Rwv37WhatInThe>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition="'$(Rwv37TestProject)' != 'false'">false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
  <Warning Text="UseOrig: $(Rwv37UseOriginalGeneratePackageOnBuild)" />
  <Warning Text="Test: $(Rwv37TestProject)" />
  <Warning Text="Gen: $(GeneratePackageOnBuild)" />
  <Warning Text="What: $(Rwv37WhatInThe)" />
```

With that, for any given project that meets that property group's condition, I would expect the values of `<Rwv37WhatInThe>` and `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` to equal each other. But really, if I build a solution having one test project and one non-test project, I get the following warnings:

```
UseOrig: false
Test: false
Gen: false
What: true
UseOrig: false
Test: true
Gen: false
What: false
```

Note that for the test project, everything is as I would expect -- i.e. both `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` and `<Rwv37WhatInThe>` are `false`. But in the non-test project, while `<Rwv37WhatInThe>` is what I would expect (`true`), `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` is, to my confusion, `false`.

I've also tried various little "non-fix" things (i.e. things that I think shouldn't matter), just on the chance that I'm wrong about them. Stuff like trying `!= 'true'` instead of `== 'false'`, for example. Nothing I've tried has helped.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get it to behave the way I want? Thanks.

**Edit:** I probably should have mentioned that I'm using VS2019 to do the build, and the projects are C# 9 .Net 5.0 libraries.

**Edit #2:** I believe I've figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

After posting this question, I went back to what I had been doing, and built the solution. It worked exactly as I would expect. I had not previously built the test project. Where I earlier said things like "when I build", really what I was doing was looking at VS2019's "error list" and/or project property pages, both of which update based on your .csproj changes in real time, regardless of whether you actually "build" or not.

So, I guess MSBuild (or something) is treating `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` differently depending on whether or not the project has actually been built yet or not.